# How do I use an if else statement in slim? I want to use the following code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

Basically, I want to have a different glyphicon for person_id 4 and a different one for everyone else. timeline-badge is a css element that helps me put the glyphicon in the right place. Please help.

```
-if person_id==4
.timeline-badge
i.glyphicon.glyphicon-phone-alt
-else
.timeline-badge
i.glyphicon.glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn
```

Comment: Is that how you are indenting? Doesn't indentation matter in `slim`? Also, shouldn't there be a space like `- if` and `- else`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can just use `class=(condition ? 'class1 when true' : 'class2 when false')`

Something like this:

```
.timeline-badge
i.glyphicon class=(person_id == 4 ? 'glyphicon-phone-alt' : 'glyphicon-bullhorn')
```

Comment: Sorry, it is working! It was a backend error that was preventing it.
To add to the question, what if I have 3 conditions, like for person_id==1, there is one glyhicon, for person_id==2, there is another and for person_id==3, there is another one?

Comment: class=(person_id == 1 ? 'glyphicon-phone-alt' : (person_id == 2 ? 'glyphicon-briefcase' : 'glyphicon-bullhorn'))
seems to work for my second question. Thanks a ton! :D

Comment: simple, call a helper method which accepts `person_id` as parameter and then evaluate the right css class and return the string of that css class. Something like: `i class=(get_person_class(person_id))` and then write your logic which returns the appropriate css class in this method.